# Pattern matching and (ereased) generic function type argument

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, type-erasure

Lets say I want to write generic function `foo` that will use pattern matching to check whether passed argument is of type of it's generic argument `T`

Naive attempt:

```
  def foo[T]: PartialFunction[Any, Boolean] = {
    case x: T =>
      true
    case _ =>
      false
  }
```

... won't work since `T` gets ereased. Compiller warning confirms that:

```
Warning:(11, 13) abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    case x: T =>
            ^
```

What is the best way to get it work?

Comment: Note that matching on type has very little to do with functional programming, and the fact that it's broken in Scala is actually a good thing (it's just a shame that it's partially supported and that the language provides workarounds like `ClassTag`).

Comment: @Travis: Eugeny's question wasn't tagged "functional programming" neither did he mention it. Scala is not just a functional programming language but also an object oriented (and even an imperative) programming language so why shouldn't it provide a workaround? Matching types is very useful in object oriented programming. If you don't want object orientation, then scala is the wrong language after all.

Comment: @Martin My complaint isn't so much about the functionality as it is about the fact that Scala mixes it up with its pattern matching (which is likely to be many people's first exposure to FP). If it had its own distinct syntax (and weren't horribly broken on generics), sure, it'd be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala has introduced `ClassTag`s for this purpose. They can be obtained by an implicit parameter, and will be automatically provided, which means you don't have to worry about the parameter when calling the method:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def foo[T](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): PartialFunction[Any, Boolean] = {
  case x: T =>
    true
  case _ =>
    false
}

val isString = foo[String] // ClassTag gets provided implicitly here

isString("Hallo") // will return true
isString(42) // will return false
```

For further explanations see the [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).